# Algolia sort by date

Tags: algolia

I know that I can use a unix timestamp to filter dates eg: **date>=1362873600,date<=1366416000**

But is it possible to sort dates using asc/desc? I would like to sort my result by newest/oldest item in a falling order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can replicate an index and set its custom ranking to use the date attribute (desc or asc).

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/sorting/